# SCNPhysicsbody velocity does not apply to child nodes

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am using Scenekit and I attached a camera to a node and applied a velocity to the physics body of the parent node. But only the parent node moves and the camera stays in place. Any ideas as to why this is happening? I need the camera to still be attached to the parent as it moves.

code:

```
    class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate{

    var playerObj : Player?
    var panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //create view and add scene
        let sceneView = self.view as SCNView
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.scene = scene

        //create camera
//        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
//        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()

        //create player
        playerObj = Player()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(playerObj!.node)
        //create floor
        let floorGeometry = SCNFloor()
        let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floorGeometry)
        floorNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: floorGeometry, options: nil))
        floorNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)
        playerObj?.node.camera = SCNCamera()

        //other setup
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

        scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, -50, 0)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.append(tapGesture)
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.append(panGesture!)

    }


    func handlePan(gestureRecognize: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        //take coordinates and transform into direction
        if let gesture = panGesture?{
            playerObj?.node.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Make(Float(gesture.translationInView(self.view).x), 0, Float(gesture.translationInView(self.view).y))
            print(gesture.translationInView(self.view))

        if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
            playerObj?.node.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
            gestureRecognize.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: physics has no concept of parent-child relationship, you have to change the velocity of all bodies that you want to move

Answer (score 0):

your camera does probably not need a physics body on its own.
If it just has to follow its parent, you could implement `-renderer:didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:` and continuously update the camera's position according to the position of the `presentationNode` of its parent.